# Insert item into list, sort it and retrieve index of item after insert

Tags: java, list, arraylist, comparator

*Precondition: the list is sorted already!*

Is that possible in another way than following:

1. add item to list
2. sort list with `Comparator` again
3. search list for item
4. return index of inserted item

I would prefer following scenario:

1. calculate index of new item if it is added to the sorted list under consideration of the `Comparator`
2. insert item at this position

Is this calculation of the position of the new item possible somehow?

**EDIT**

I should mention, that I'm using a foreign library, I need this thing only, to keep to lists in sync (items and selection state in my case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is already sorted then use  Collections.binarySearch(list, element, comparator) with the same Comparator which was used for sorting. It will return the insertion position i. Insert the element with list.add(i, element). If i < 0 then use i = -i - 1 as insertion point

Answer (score 2):

Use a `TreeSet` and you won't have to worry about sorting the collection. Especially good if you intend to do this several times.

Answer (score 0):

You may calculate this index but your own. The main problem is to define moreThan() operation(In example I suppose you have ascending order). i is the index you want to know.

```
if(insertedElement.moreThan(list.get(list.size()-1))){
            i = list.size();    
}else{
            for(i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                if(list.get(i).moreThan(insertedElement)){
                    break;
                }
            }
 }
```

After that use `add(index, element)` method, new element will be added, next elements will be shifted and the list order will be saved.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about `list.get(list.size())` in the first line.  It seems like a recipe for some kind of exception.

Comment: list.get(list.size()) is when inserted element more than the biggest element you are already have. I had a mistake, I corrected my answer.

Comment: No, you haven't corrected your answer.  It still throws an exception.  -1.

Comment: I checked it once again(I use list of integers) and I don't see other mistakes. Leave your downvote but show on which data it will work incorrect.

Comment: I want to repeat my question. You are saying I have a bug, you downvoted me. Ok, I agree. But now show me please where is this bug, on which dataset this code will be failed.

Comment: My sincerest apologies.  I have been testing this again today. Your bug is gone.  I'm not sure which edit of yours removed it, but I can't reproduce it now.  Thank you for persisting with this.